# Jquery select multiple date ranges in HTML Calendar

Tags: jquery, calendar, overlapping

I use an HTML calendar where I can select multiple date ranges. How can I prevent time periods from overlap?

- First click select first day
- Second click select range (must be AFTER the first click day)
- Third click select next first day
- Fourth click select next range

My idea is to do it via the index(), but I don't know how....

I am glad about tips and help. I can't get any further on my own.

```js
$("td.day").click(function() {

    if ($("td.firstClick").length == 0 && $(this).hasClass("reserved") == false) {
        $(this).addClass("firstClick");
    }
    
    if ($("td.firstClick").length > 0 && $(this).hasClass("firstClick") == false) {
        var tds = $("td.day");
        var firstClick = $(".firstClick");
        var firstClickIndex = tds.index(firstClick);
        var currentIndex = tds.index(this);
        
        tds.filter(function() {
            var idx = tds.index(this);
            return idx > firstClickIndex && idx < currentIndex;
            }).addClass("reserved");
    
        $(".firstClick").addClass("checkin").removeClass("firstClick");
        $(this).addClass("checkout");
    }
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table tr td {
  width: 14%;
}
table tr td:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.firstClick {
  background: green;
}
.checkin {
  background: yellow;
}
.checkout {
  background: red;
}
.reserved {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="7"><b>2016</b>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="7"><i>November</i>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>mon</th>
    <th>tue</th>
    <th>wed</th>
    <th>thu</th>
    <th>fri</th>
    <th>sat</th>
    <th>sun</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="day">1</td>
    <td class="day">2</td>
    <td class="day">3</td>
    <td class="day">4</td>
    <td class="day">5</td>
    <td class="day">6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="day">7</td>
    <td class="day">8</td>
    <td class="day">9</td>
    <td class="day">10</td>
    <td class="day">11</td>
    <td class="day">12</td>
    <td class="day">13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="day">14</td>
    <td class="day">15</td>
    <td class="day">16</td>
    <td class="day">17</td>
    <td class="day">18</td>
    <td class="day">19</td>
    <td class="day">20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="day">21</td>
    <td class="day">22</td>
    <td class="day">23</td>
    <td class="day">24</td>
    <td class="day">25</td>
    <td class="day">26</td>
    <td class="day">27</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="day">28</td>
    <td class="day">29</td>
    <td class="day">30</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you add the `reserved` class to the range of days, check if any of them are already reserved.

```js
$("td.day").click(function() {

  if ($("td.firstClick").length == 0 && !$(this).is(".reserved, .checkin, .checkout")) {
    $(this).addClass("firstClick");
    return;
  }

  // Click again to toggle first date
  if ($(this).hasClass("firstClick")) {
    $(this).removeClass("firstClick");
    return;
  }

  if ($("td.firstClick").length > 0 && !$(this).hasClass("firstClick")) {
    var tds = $("td.day");
    var firstClick = $(".firstClick");
    var firstClickIndex = tds.index(firstClick);
    var currentIndex = tds.index(this);

    if (currentIndex < firstClickIndex) {
      alert("Checkout has to be after checkin");
      return;
    }

    var range = tds.filter(function() {
      var idx = tds.index(this);
      return idx > firstClickIndex && idx < currentIndex;
    });
    if (range.filter(".reserved, .checkin, .checkout").length > 0) {
      alert("Can't select overlapping range");
      return;
    }
    range.addClass("reserved");
    $(".firstClick").addClass("checkin").removeClass("firstClick");
    $(this).addClass("checkout");
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr td {
  width: 14%;
}

table tr td:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.firstClick {
  background: green;
}

.checkin {
  background: yellow;
}

.checkout {
  background: red;
}

.reserved {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="7"><b>2016</b>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="7"><i>November</i>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>mon</th>
    <th>tue</th>
    <th>wed</th>
    <th>thu</th>
    <th>fri</th>
    <th>sat</th>
    <th>sun</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="day">1</td>
    <td class="day">2</td>
    <td class="day">3</td>
    <td class="day">4</td>
    <td class="day">5</td>
    <td class="day">6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="day">7</td>
    <td class="day">8</td>
    <td class="day">9</td>
    <td class="day">10</td>
    <td class="day">11</td>
    <td class="day">12</td>
    <td class="day">13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="day">14</td>
    <td class="day">15</td>
    <td class="day">16</td>
    <td class="day">17</td>
    <td class="day">18</td>
    <td class="day">19</td>
    <td class="day">20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="day">21</td>
    <td class="day">22</td>
    <td class="day">23</td>
    <td class="day">24</td>
    <td class="day">25</td>
    <td class="day">26</td>
    <td class="day">27</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="day">28</td>
    <td class="day">29</td>
    <td class="day">30</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello and thank you Barmar! I will test it.
Can you also tell me how I can prevent the second click on a day before the first day is executed?

Comment: `if (firstClickIndex > currentIndex)` will detect this case.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. Already found it :-)

Comment: Hello again, I noticed that an overlap is possible for tag 2. But this one has the correct class "reserved". Do you have any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by tag 2? Do you mean the checkout date? It has `class="checkout"` but not `class="reserved"`

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. If I first select 8-12, then try 7-9, it allows it. The range of the new rservation is only 8, which is the checkin date of the first reservation, but not a reserved date.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! I'm still trying to remove the class again by clicking on a day "reserved". That also works so far. Only with several calendar tables this does not work. The checkin or checkout can be in another month...

`$(".day").click(function() {
 if ($(this).is(".reserved")) {
  $(this).removeClass("reserved");
  $(this).prevUntil(".checkin").removeClass("reserved");
  $(this).nextUntil(".checkout").removeClass("reserved");
  $(this).prevAll(".checkin").first().removeClass("checkin");
  $(this).nextAll(".checkout").first().removeClass("checkout");
 }
}); `

Comment: If you want to do that, it would probably be better to work with dates, not element indexes. Why not use a real datepicker widget?

Comment: I wanted to implement my own solution. In the meantime I also added a "data-date="2023-06-19"" to each day. But even there I do not get further to address these.